# Facing cache issue on CMS page

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm facing one issue on magento2.

I have created one CMS page and want to display current CART items on cms page.

So i have created on test.phtml file and call from CMS page.

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" cacheable="false" template="Magento_Theme::test.phtml"}}
```

Whatever i have written in test.phtml file will only display if i'll clean my cache. It's not display directly if i'll update anything.

I have already written cacheable="false" but it's not working.

Can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,

Comment: it's probably because oyur page is cached. you only set cachable=false for the block.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Philipp.

Finally i resolved this using below code in Design section.

<referenceContainer name="content">
   <block name="test" cacheable="false"/>
</referenceContainer>